# Can array bounds checking be disabled in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio, bounds-checker

I know that this was an advanced compiler option in previous versions of Visual Studio, is there a way to disable array bounds checking in Visual Studio 2008? There's no option for it that I can see.

Comment: you might be interested in Rico Mariani's post: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/07/12/663642.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that was a pretty insightful article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  Not having array bound checking in C/C++ is how Microsoft got into such deep trouble with malware.  It is a no-no in managed code.  For and For Each loops will run without bound checking if the JIT compiler can detect that the begin- and end-indices are within bounds.  This is one of the reasons that the For loop "TO" value is only evaluated once.